# Eddington-Barbier approximation next term for flux

Tags: flux, radiative-transfer

When adding a term to E-B approx it should lead to this for the astronomical flux.
$\frac{F}{\pi }\approx S\left(\tau =\frac{2}{3}\right)+\frac{5}{18}\frac{d^2S}{d\tau ^2}_{\tau =\frac{2}{3}}$

S is the source function, tau is the optical density, F is the astronomical flux

usually the E-B approx is just $\frac{F}{\pi }\approx S\left(\tau =\frac{2}{3}\right)$ now we want the second term also.

I don't know how to start or get here...

Comment: Only someone steeped in the subject would stand any chance of understanding this question. Could you give a bit of context and explain all the symbols?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.07026 might be helpful

Comment: And there is another completely different derivation: https://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1965ZA.....61..237D (paper in German, but possibly one can follow its detailed mathematical derivation even without command of the language)

Comment: Thank you for these

Comment: Looks like a Taylor expansion around a minimum at $\tau = 2/3$.